# what is the best oil/fat to use to season a cast iron skillet

Tags: cast-iron

What is best oil/fat for seasoning cast iron cookware?  I've read veg oils, lard, combinations of oil/fat types. Anyone out there help?!

Comment: That might not be the best question on the topic though ... there was one a long time ago where someone explained which oils resulted in a hard finish, and which ones were slightly tacky when cool, but amazingly slick when heated up.